# Proper use of quotes for output of JavaScript in a variable

Tags: php, javascript, html, quotes

I am creating a chunk of HTML/JavaScript with the below code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid = '$user_id' ORDER BY DATE desc LIMIT 5")or die (mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    $source = $row[source];
    $source = "'$source'";

    $p = $p.'<div id="red-div"><div id="smartass"><div id="image"><img src="thumbs/'.$user_image.'" /></div><div id="playsong"><a href="#" onclick="playsong(';
    $p = p.$source;
    $p = $p.'); return false;"><img src="play.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a>'.$row[artist].' - '.$row[title].'</div></div><div id="post-comment">'.$row[comment].'</div><div id="post-date">'.$row[date].'</div></div><div id="dotted-line"></div>';

}
```

I then update a part of my page with the following code:

```
parent.document.getElementById('posts').innerHTML = '<?php echo $p; ?>';
```

For some reason no matter how I quote or enter `$source` into `playsong('')`; I loose the `''` in `playsong();` resulting in something like `playsong(theSongVariable);` and that of course does not work.

How do I properly quote or output the `''` to make sure they stay in `playsong('')`;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: also, shouldn't

```
$p = p.$source;
```

be

```
$p = $p.$source;
```

btw, don't forget you can use the .= operator. like

```
$p .= $source;
```

edit2: 
try outputting your $p for analysis using (will change < to &lt;

```
echo htmlspecialchars($p);
```

Edited to remove JS line. clearly not outputted from within a <?php ?> block. (should've had my coffee first)

Comment: Of course its a missing $... Thanks that fixed it. And the JavaScript does work  because the <?php echo $p; ?> is processed then sent back and put into the JavaScript and then the JavaScript executes when the page loads yea?

Answer (score 3):

If possible you should use [`json_encode`](http://docs.php.net/json_encode) to build a JavaScript string declaration and `htmlspialchars` to use it as a HTML attribute value:

```
$onclick = 'playsong('.json_encode($row['source']).'); return false';
$p .= '<div id="red-div"><div id="smartass"><div id="image"><img src="thumbs/'.htmlspecialchars($user_image).'" /></div>';
$p .= '<div id="playsong"><a href="#" onclick="'.htmlspecialchars($onclick).'"><img src="play.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a>';
$p .= htmlspecialchars($row[artist].' - '.$row[title]).'</div></div>';
$p .= '<div id="post-comment">'.htmlspecialchars($row['comment']).'</div>';
$p .= '<div id="post-date">'.$row['date'].'</div></div><div id="dotted-line"></div>';
```

Oh, and [IDs must be unique in documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id).

Comment: Not savvy with json but will read up on htmlspecialchars() thanks.

Comment: I think json_export() should be json_encode() in your example

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [addslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function on your $p string. I think its primary purpose relates to building queries for databases, but it may work for in your case as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to escape strings depending the context in which you use them.

In your specific case you should use:

`echo json_encode(htmlspecialchars($p, ENT_QUOTES, *your charset*));`

[htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) helps you to escape HTML sequences so that you don't have funky things such as `</script>` in the Javascript part.

[json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) makes sure that your string is valid as a JavaScript sequence.

These are very important security concepts because otherwise there are serious issues such as [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) or even [XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) if you give users special permissions on your site.

As we're on the topic, make sure that your $user_id is a validated value because otherwise you are vulnerable for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). For example, $user_id could be "1' OR '1'='1".

Hth

Comment: Is mysql_real_escape_string() the best way to secure my $user_id variable and others like it?

Comment: That is an option. I did not actively use PHP for more than one year now but as I remember they were discussing the newer slower mysqli interface which allowed placeholders in queries. I'd give that a shot.